# how do I get irb to -really- reload my class code?

Tags: ruby, irb

Got some code in ruby that looks like (method in the Product class):

```
  def merge_prices_with_suppliers(suppliers)
    data = []
    phs = self.prices
    suppliers_in = phs.map { |ph| ph.supplier_id}.uniq()
    for serv in suppliers_in  
      logger.debug serv
      data_for_supplier = phs.select{|ph| ph.supplier_id== serv}
      debugger
      s = (suppliers.select{|s| s.id.to_s == serv }[0])
      if s.nil? || s.name.nil?
         name = "none" 
      else
         name = s.name
      end
      logger.debug "#{name} #{serv}"
      data.push([name, data_for_supplier.map{|ph| {date: ph.date, amount: ph.amount} }])
    end
   data 
   end
```

I'm reloading and re-running this with:

```
 reload! and g = Product.by_name( 'thenamehere') and  g.merge_prices_with_suppliers(suppliers)
```

OK so I make some changes because the select statement isn't working correctly. Then I `reload!`. When I reload and redo the "get" of the object, the new code is not present.  The `by_name` code is pretty simple: `Game.where(name: name).first` (using mongoid). I've also tried `reload!` on a line by itself, no luck. I've tried setting the object to nil before reloading with no luck. I've tried making a completely different object, no luck.

But if I close irb and start it again, the new code is right there.

Why is `reload!` not actually reloading my code? I've read other questions on here about this issue but they didn't help.